# Weird Result During the fork() function in Fibonacci with different Code Order

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

When I am trying to use the `fork()` function to let the children process to recursively call `doFib`, I get weird results that `sum1` and `sum2` were property set in the parent process, but when I want to use them to calculate the result, it turns out that they are not properly set. However, if I replace the first while loop just before the `pid2 = fork()`, I could get the right result. Could anybody explain why this happens?

```
static void doFib(int n, int doPrint)
{
    int result;

    pid_t pid1;
    int status1;
    int sum1 = 0;
    pid_t pid2;
    int status2;
    int sum2 = 0;
    //printf("my pid is: %d\n", getpid());
    //test for less number
    if(n < 2)
    {
        if(doPrint)
        {
            printf("%d\n", n);
        }
        _exit(n);//result the value of F0 and F1
    }
    //not initial, need fork here
    pid1 = fork();
    if(pid1 == 0)
    {//in children 1
        doFib(n-1, 0);
    }

    pid2 = fork();
    if(pid2 == 0){
        doFib(n-2, 0);
    }

    while((pid1 = waitpid(-1, &status1, 0)) > 0){
        if(WIFEXITED(status1))
            sum1 = WEXITSTATUS(status1);
    }
    while((pid2 = waitpid(-1, &status2, 0)) > 0){
        if(WIFEXITED(status2))
            sum2 = WEXITSTATUS(status2);
    }

    result = sum1 + sum2;
    if(doPrint)
    {
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }else
    {//in the children
        _exit(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check on the return status of `waitpid` is incorrect.  It returns the pid of the child process on success, and -1 on error.  You don't need to do this in a loop.  Just do it once, and grab the return value if it's successful.

```
if ((pid1 = waitpid(-1, &status1, 0)) != -1) {
    if(WIFEXITED(status1))
        sum1 = WEXITSTATUS(status1);
}
if ((pid2 = waitpid(-1, &status2, 0)) != -1) {
    if(WIFEXITED(status2))
        sum2 = WEXITSTATUS(status2);
}
```

That said, calculation fibonacci numbers recursively is inefficient, and especially so when the recursion is done via forking.  This also limits the number returns to 255, as the return value of a process is only a single byte wide.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand the function about the fork and waitpid better now! This is just a start quiz for us to understand these functions and we will use them in the future assignments...

Comment: @gangdou Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: Just learned how to accept an answer LOL, always come here but first time to ask a question...